# Http Response Splitting veracode flaw while using request.getCookies()

Tags: java, veracode

I am getting all the cookies from the request object and then further filtering out the cookie i need and adding the same in the response.

But this give me Http Response splitting veracode flaw.

```
  Optional<Cookie> optional = Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
    .filter(x -> ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML("myCookie").equals(x.getName())
    .findFirst();

if (optional.isPresent()) {
  Cookie tkCookie = optional.get();
  tkCookie.setMaxAge(0);
  response.addCookie(tkCookie);
}
```

How to prevent this veracode flaw here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?